# querySelectorAll method is not supported with IE11 in standards mode

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer

I'm having an issue with IE11. The `document.querySelectorAll` is causing some issues.

Whenever I use it via the console like so:

```
document.querySelectorAll('.test_class');
```

I get the following error:

```
Object doesn't support property or method 'querySelector'
```

I'm not in quirks mode as I found that this was an issue for others that had this problem. I have also added the `<!DOCTYPE html>` to my Web page.

What am I missing?

Comment: are you in compatibility mode?

Answer (score 2):

Here is how you can do it:

`let classes = document.querySelectorAll('.test_class')
    Array.prototype.forEach.call(classes, element => {
      console.log("class",element)
    })`

Answer (score 1):

I just found the answer to this almost as soon as I posted the question:

The issue was to add the following metatag:

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1" />
```

Found this here: http://corpus.hubwiz.com/2/angularjs/25632927.html

Hope it helps.

Comment: On a legacy project, I am also facing similar issue and removing compatibility mode from IE. Solves my issue without adding meta and doc type tags.