# JavaScript code working on other browsers but not working on IE11, why?

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer

I am using this JS code to add a class on a activate bootstrap 4 navigation link, and on most browsers it is working, but on IE11 not. Any idea why?

```
"use strict";
var nav = document.querySelector('.navbar');
var links = nav.querySelectorAll('.highlight');
  links.forEach(function(link){
    if (link.href == window.location.href.split("#")[0]) {
      link.classList.add('active');
    }
  });

links.forEach(function(link){

  link.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    links.forEach(function(link){
      link.classList.remove('active');
    });
      this.classList.add('active');
  });
});

var kontaktLink = document.querySelector('.kontaktLink');
var navBarToggle = document.getElementById('navbarSupportedContent');
var togglerButton = document.querySelector('.navbar-toggler');

kontaktLink.addEventListener('click', function() {
  if (navBarToggle.classList.contains('show')) {
    navBarToggle.classList.remove('show');
    navBarToggle.classList.add('collapse');
    togglerButton.classList.add('collapsed');
    togglerButton.setAttribute('aria-expanded','false');
  }
});
```

Comment: Did you check the console for error messages? Also please create a [mcve].

Comment: IE11 doesnt support as much of ECMAScript as Edge, Chrome, FF, etc does

Comment: *querySelectorAll* returns a *NodeList*, to which the [*forEach* method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList/forEach) has only been recently added. IE 11 doesn't support it.

Comment: My guess is it's because you're calling `forEach` on the result of `querySelectorAll`. Bootstrap requires jQuery, and jQuery makes stuff like this **a lot** easier and shorter. I'd look into using it instead.

Comment: @RobG You should post your comment as answer

Answer (score 1):

Because of IE... :)

Check out your console output for errors. There will be some function that is not supported in ie 11

[Unsupported querySelectorAll](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45260298/queryselectorall-method-is-not-supported-with-ie11-in-standards-mode)

[Maybe unsupported classList property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8098406/code-with-classlist-does-not-work-in-ie)

[Or maybe even forEach function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47534102/js-foreach-loops-in-ie11)

Answer (score 1):

IE11 only support up to ECMAScript 5, whereas other more modern browsers use ECMAScript 6. They don't intent on updating it either.
ES 5 basically has less features for Javascript than ES 6, so that could be the culprit.

I like to use https://caniuse.com/ to see which functions are supported by which browser.

For example, it looks like querySelectorAll is supported by IE11:
https://caniuse.com/#search=queryselectorall

EDIT:
If you do wish to use ES6 features in IE11, you can have a look at BabelJS.
https://babeljs.io/

Comment: NodeLists aren't part of ECMAScript, they're host objects. The relevant specification is the [*DOM Living Standard*](https://dom.spec.whatwg.org/#interface-nodelist). In regard to ECMAScript, Array.prototype.forEach has been supported since IE 9.

Answer (score 0):

So, IE11 does not support forEach on a nodeList. I solved this problem by expanding the nodeList.prototype:
NodeList.prototype.forEach = Array.prototype.forEach;